# What is the opposite of "for free"?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

On [Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/for_free.html) all the antonyms mean *"expensive"*.

But I need one word as the opposite of *"for free"* at all regardless of the amount.

That is *"on paid basis"* but something more shortly

For example in the sentence, *"Try it for free. Then continue on paid basis"*

An adverb would be the best.

---

Just found the following text in [A guide to paid subscriptions](https://substack.com/going-paid-guide):

> When trying to decide whether to go **paid**, start by taking...

So, can we use *"paid"* as an adverb?

---

Ok, I've got the point regarding *"go paid"*, I see I can simply specify fixed price after saying about free feature (but it's not my case) and the second part is redundant in my example sentence where it's implied that the next features are paid.

Still, I would like to find the general opposite of *"for free"* answering to the question *"how"* (how to go: for free or ?) more broadly regardless of the context. *"How to go"* and not *"what feature"*: free or paid. That is not an adjective.

I've also found *"go for paid"*. For example, going for paid is the opposite of going with organic (free) advertising of website here: [Paid vs Organic; Digital Marketing's big debate](https://www.strategy-plus.net/articles/paid-advertising-organic-advertising)

Is it correct to say *"... Then you may continue the next stages for paid or stop our cooperation ..."* ?

Comment: This is a good question.  I can't think of a very short answer, but "for a fee" or "for a price" might work.

Comment: I would like to see a bit more context to suggest a way of phrasing this. One possibility would be to say *it has a nominal price/fee*, if you want to emphasize the fact that the price is very low but not zero.

Comment: An example sentence showing how you would like to use this word would be helpful. The opposite of "for free" (gratis) is "paid", for example "Having us wash your dog is a paid service, but we will clean his ears for free whenever you bring him in for a checkup." How you would exactly phrase it in a sentence would depend on the context though.

Comment: "Continuing on a paid basis" would be a subscription, wouldn't it? "Try it for free, then subscribe if you find it valuable." Or do you mean "pay a one time fee after you've had a chance to try it for free"?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. For some period of time the person paying can get some of these tasks done for free, then if they like the service, they can continue getting those tasks done, but will have to pay?

Comment: Possibly worth noting that in British English, many people regard 'free' as the default usage, and 'for free' as an Americanism.

Comment: One example I often struggle to find the English for is "is this motorway free or... "
I can't find a simple adjective to indicate that it's a toll road

Comment: TANSTAAFL: "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch" comes to mind.

Comment: One very simple antonym that exactly parallels "for free" is "_for money_".

Comment: You either offer it for **free** or you charge a **fee**.  Those are the two opposites you seek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite of *for free* is *for a fee*.

> The lollipops are free but there is a fee for the caramels.

*Paid's* opposite is *unpaid*.  Although in some instances *for free* can be the opposite of *paid*.  In your example sentence you need to use the word *fee*.

> Try it for free. Then continue for **a fee**.

Comment: +1 For a fee is a good choice I think.

Comment: Yes, it's short. But is the same as _"for a fixed price"_? What about freelancing where the cost is estimated depending on each specific job? Maybe _"for a cost"_ ?

Comment: @stckvrw - A fee is a generalized reference to a charge (or cost).  It's very general and can refer to a fixed price, a freelancing charge, or contractual amount.  If you want to use *for a cost* you will be understood.  You could also use *for some money, for a price, for a charge, or for the exchange of cash*.  Just because it can be said, however, doesn't mean it is good communication.  I would use *for a fee*.   What is your hesitancy to use *fee*?

Answer (score 6):

The opposite of "for free" is "paid." [This has a few definitions, including:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/paid)

> 1. being given money for something
> 2. a paid job, activity, or period of time is one for which you are given money
> 3. a paid worker, employee, etc. is given money for work that they do
> 4. a paid service is one which people must pay for in order to have it

Comment: You mean "paid" as an adjective and not as an adverb, right?

Comment: Yes, as an adjective.

Comment: "Paid" cannot be used as an adverb; you'd need to rearrange the sentence so that you can use an adjective instead.

Comment: But does this work for products? You can get "free beer", but I've never heard "paid beer".

Comment: @alphabet The adjective _"paid"_ is the opposite of the adjective _"free"_. But the question is about _"for free"_ which is not an adjective

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of *free* (or *gratis*) is *[paid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paid)* (being or having been paid or paid for) or *[pay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pay)* (requiring payment) as an adjective.

> The streaming service offered two plans, a free plan with ads and a paid plan without ads.

> There are very few pay toilets left in the US.

*Paid* can't be used as an adverb to convey the opposite of *gratis*.

> When trying to decide whether to go paid, start by taking...

In this example *go paid* means to change something from being gratis to being something that requires payment. A similar construction is "to go pro" or change from being an amateur to being a professional.

I think we're having a hard time coming up with an exact match for your example sentence, because the "continue on a paid basis" is already implied by the "try" when you say "Try it for free." If something is always available free, we wouldn't say "try"; we would just say "It's free!"

Typically, we see text like:

> Try it free for one month. After that it is only $5 a month.
> The first print is free. After that each print is only $10.

Comment: Good answer, but I would emphasise that the phrase “go paid” (or, worse, “go pro”) is actually not very good English - marketing and advertising text in American English uses this construction (“go _[adjective]_”) a lot, but it is grammatically incorrect (replace “go” with any other verb and you’ll see why), and so is not suitable for use in general text.

Comment: @KrisW There are plenty of set phrases and idioms that are ungrammatical if you swap out a word, but yes “go paid” is informal and a bit jargony. Go or turn pro is used mostly in sports journalism, which can be like a completely different language sometimes, so probably is not the tone a learner wants :)

Comment: Yep, I agree about set phrases, but I don’t think “go paid” is one yet. It’s pretty new, and it is something I have seen only on advertising for web-based services.  To my (British English) eyes, it’s not at all correct, and I suspect it’s a phrase that has leaked from developers to marketing.  Many developers do not have English as a first language, so you can find these odd not-quite-English constructions popping up a lot in software documentation (I am a software developer).  I much prefer your final suggestion: grammatically correct, and clearly explains the offer.

Comment: @KrisW Constructions using _go_ as a linking verb – such as _go [adjective]_ – are not new at all, and not particularly related to marketing. Milk can go sour, bread can go stale, her face went pale, my aunt has gone crazy, some wizards go bad (one in particular went as bad as he could go), things can go wrong (arguably adverbial), etc. It is often fairly informal in register, but it is a perfectly integrated and grammatical part of standard English. What is marketing-speak is the construction where _[adjective]_ describes a customer’s relationship or tier (free, pro, wireless, etc.)

Comment: @stckvrw I think you missed my point that if you aren't going to say something more than "pay to keep using it", adding more after the "try for free" is redundant. If it's a free trial, that implies I will eventually need to pay something for it.

Comment: @stckvrw That's a great update. I'm at work and don't have the time to address it right now, but I do appreciate that you are staying engaged with your question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet good point. I was really thinking of “go paid“ when I said that, but yes, the general case is common. After some thought, the basis of my objection is that sour, stale, crazy and even “pro” are adjectives that, if you applied them to their subject nouns (“sour milk”, “stale bread”, “pro wrestler”, etc.), would convey the same meaning as the “go __” construction. My objection to “go paid” is that it breaks this rule: a “paid customer” is someone who has received, or is receiving, money from the business. To me that sounds odd, and also has negative connotations of dishonesty.

Comment: @KrisW Even that does have its parallels, though, where _go X_ means ‘start doing/using/preferring/liking X’ – for example, the well-known adage that ‘once you go black, you never go back’ (where ‘go black’ means ‘start dating/having sex with black people’, not turning black yourself), or ‘go mobile/wireless’ (get rid of your landline phone/wired Internet connection), or even with brand names like ‘go Mac’ (become a Mac user) or ‘go Nike’ (start using Nike shoes/clothes).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The last examples you gave (Mac and Nike) are exactly what I meant by “American marketing usage”.  The first example is intended to be humorous, “go black” is half of a rhyming couplet with “never go back”, and grammar here takes a second place to scansion. (The “Go Mac“ one, incidentally, is a play on the “go black” rhyme - I heard the full phrase used a lot when I worked at Apple).
But use in advertising tag-lines doesn’t make something acceptable in general text. Advertising copy bends rules for dramatic effect, but often (deliberately) sacrifices accuracy and clarity,.

Comment: @KrisW While I agree that marketese has probably been the driving factor behind many of these, I don’t think that’s the full story. It’s used by regular people as well, and the ‘once you go black’ example definitely did not originate with marketers (my gut instinct is that it _predates_ the marketese use). I believe the ability of _go_ to take a complement describing not the subject itself but something the subject uses/likes/does, while limited, happened organically and was (ab)used by marketers – not the other way around. Ungrammatical marketese rarely catches on.

Comment: I didn’t claim that “once you go black...” originated in advertising/marking, and I don’t dispute that these have currency in spoken English,  but I think you’re missing my original point here: this isn’t a question of whether the phrase is or is not “English”. It’s an issue of _where_ you should use such casual phrases. As this is a forum for _learners_ of English, we should try to give the most generally-usable answers to questions, and “go paid” is not, by a long way, something that would be universally accepted as proper English. Rule bending is a privilege of the fluent speaker...

Answer (score 2):

Even though the term does not perfectly fit your use case it may be worth mentioning that *for free* in the general sense means "at no cost", not only monetary; the logical opposite would be **[at a cost](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20a%20cost)**: *Chaos comes for free, order comes at a cost.* [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_a_price#English) makes the point that the phrase is used for unwelcome consequences; this includes, for most people, paying an amount of money, but that is not the typical meaning.

Still: It can probably be used for something that costs money. *The trial version is free, the premium version comes at a cost of 20 dollars;* but that's a bit unusual and stilted and borders on the ironic.

Comment: "cost" is most correct, because paid et al. imply money, which "free" does not.

Answer (score 1):

> "Try it for free. Then continue on paid basis"

"Try it for fee" already implies that it's not normally free. Therefore, "continue on a paid basis" is redundant.

Comment: Please see my second update to the question. So, can it be _"continue paid"_? And what the difference between _"at cost"_ and _"for a cost"_ ?

Comment: @stckvrw "at cost" is used to indicate that there will be no markup, e.g. "As a gesture of good will, we can sell you a replacement at cost". "For a cost" can be used, but could be considered a harsh use of language, since saying "this will cost you" may have ominous overtones. Marketers prefer to sell benefits and indicate a price, rather than talking about costs.

Comment: Yes, you're right - more shortly way to say _"on paid basis"_. I know I can just rearrange the sentence to use the adjective _"paid"_. But I'm curious about the first option

Comment: @stckvrw btw 'more shortly' is not correct. You can say 'more concisely' instead. Can you clarify what the 'first option' is you're referring to? Do you mean 'continue paid'?

Comment: The first option is _"Then you may continue the next stages **on paid basis**"_ and the second option (rearranging the sentence) is _"Then the next stages **are paid**"_

Comment: @stckvrw btw it's "on a paid basis", not "on paid basis".

Comment: @stckvrw I think, fundamentally, the problem is that it's not often that people need to communicate that their products or services incur a fee, without actually specifying the fee. A restaurant would never need to say "we offer food on a paid basis".

Comment: @stckvrw Right, but you would usually assume that someone offering products or services will charge you money unless otherwise stated. And if they do state that certain things are free, that will imply other things are paid. There is no valid contract unless both parties are clear about what the charge is before continuing, or unless the vendor has made a legally valid attempt to make their charges clear on signage. Therefore, it's usually not useful to talk about there being a charge without being more specific about the charge.

Answer (score 0):

Another word for this is [**commercial**,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commercial) although this can have other meanings too. It's a bit more formal than *paid* is. You wouldn't use it in those specific sentences, though.

Comment: Pretty sure *commercial* is not the opposite of *for free* in any case.